# postgres reverse jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, array, jsonb

Postgres 13
I have a table with jsonb array and I need to revert the array. Any idea on how I can do that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_reverse(anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS $$
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT $1[i]
    FROM generate_subscripts($1,1) AS s(i)
    ORDER BY i DESC
);
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' STRICT IMMUTABLE;

create table route (
   session_id serial primary key, 
   name varchar(20), 
   data jsonb
);

insert into route(name, data)
VALUES('NY-LA',
'["{\"x\":40.83382,\"y\":-75.051552}", "{\"x\":33.740055,\"y\":-118.199982}"]'
);

insert into route(name, data)
VALUES('NY-CH',
'["{\"x\":40.83382,\"y\":-75.051552}", "{\"x\":39.740055,\"y\":-90.199982}"]');

SELECT * FROM route;
```

What I need is to revert the column data. E.g. `select data->0->'x' from route where id = 1;` returns `39.740055`. I [found](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_reverse) `array_reverse()` function suggested by Postgres, but do not understand how to convert jsonb into ARRAY so that I can use `array_reverse(array)` function.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that the elements of your arrays are simple strings due to the escaping of the `"`. There is no key `"x"` in your sample data, so `data -> 0 -> 'x'` won't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

anyarray means any SQL-level array.  It does not cover the JSONB subtype.  You will need a function specifically for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_reverse(jsonb) RETURNS jsonb AS $$
SELECT jsonb_agg(value order by ordinality desc) 
    FROM jsonb_array_elements($1) with ordinality;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```